# How to find the length of a list based on a condition in R

Tags: r

**The problem**

I would like to find a length of a list.

**The expected output**

I would like to find the length based on a condition.

**Example**

Suppose that I have a list of 4 elements as follows:

```
myve <–list(1,2,3,0)
```

Here I have 4 elements, one of them is zero. How can I find the length by extracting the zero values? Then, if the length is `> 1`I would like to substruct one. That is:

If the length is `4` then, I would like to have `4-1=3`. So, the output should be `3`.

**Note**

Please note that I am working with a problem where the zero values may be changed from one case to another. For example, For the first list may I have only one 0 value, while for the second list may I have 2 or 3 zero values.

The values are always positive or zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sapply to extract the ones different to zeros and sum to count them

```
sum(sapply(myve, function(x) x!=0))
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to apply the condition to each element. This will produce a list of boolean, then you sum it to get the number of `True` elements (i.e. validation your condition).

In your case:

```
sum(myve != 0)
```

In a more complex case, where the confition is expressed by a function `f`:

```
sapply(myve, f)
```

Comment: Maybe `sum(myve != 0)` is better. Imagine the list has a perfectly legal *negative* value. It is less than `1` and therefore not counted.